# Bootstrap CSS effects not working when using Truffle Webpack

Tags: css, webpack, bootstrap-4, truffle

I am using truffle webpack for dapp development. For HTML page design I am using bootstrap. While testing my web pages (via HTML) pages are rendering properly. But when I run the dapp using 'npm run dev' the HTML pages loose the CSS effect. I made some changes in the webpack.config.js file (screenshots below) after reading some responses on StackExchange but that didn't help.

Please suggest how can I solve this issue.

For reference, I have given screenshots of the HTML page, webpack.config.js and app.js files as below.

Best Regards

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf4iV.png)

[webpack.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OLas.png)

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RptLb.png)

Comment: Have you tried using absolute paths? I see you are importing css with `../stylesheets/app.css` and that may be breaking when you bundle files together.

Comment: I have added below line of code:                                                             
     // Import the page's CSS. Webpack will know what to do with it.
      import "../stylesheets/app.css";
      import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';                                                                                     this has changed the layout but not completely...inside my HTML I am using css from bootstrapcdn. Can you please help me how to import it to js. Pardon me for my noob status in web designing.